# Data read from Excel is being treated as object

Tags: vbscript, testcomplete

I have the following data in Excel as text.

```
Sys.Process("Client").WPFObject("HwndSource:  Main").WPFObject("Main").WPFObject("WorkspaceControl")
```

I wanted to read this data from Excel and I wanted create new object by removing the last object. In this case new object will be

```
Set newobject = Sys.Process("Client").WPFObject("HwndSource:  Main").WPFObject("Main")
```

The challenge I am facing is when I read from Excel and assign the read string to a varible, testcomplete is treating it as an object instead of string.

Comment: Can you put here the code that reads the value?